# Eclipse S&R Regex - Add NULL check before pointer use (C++, Fedora18)

Tags: c++, regex, linux, eclipse

after messing with the eclipse regex I want to know if it is possible 
to use search and replace in order to find "->" (pointer use) and take the member before it
and verify it's not NULL

Original code:

```
mAnyPointer->GetSomething();
```

New code:

```
if(mAnyPointer!=NULL)
{
    mAnyPointer->GetSomething();
}
else
{
    throw...;
}
```

I've experienced the regex of adding, but is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Comment: If you have an idea using another software or some other method, feel free to add. I'm open minded :)